# Namespace Extension for Dropbox-like Windows application

Tags: windows

I'm interested (for learning purposes) in creating an Namespace Extension for Windows that is similar to Dropbox or SkyDrive. What I'd like to do is integrate directly with Windows Explorer like those services that appear as a "connected drive":

[image: Skydrive]

When clicking on the connected folder, I'll be interacting with my own site to determine what contents to display.

I'm familiar with WebDAV, and I've actually created something similar to this with WebDAV but now I want to move away from "mapping drives". I want an installable application that, after initial setup like SkyDrive or Dropbox, would just appear as a connected drive and be authenticated as the user.

I've never created a Namespace Extension but my research is pointing towards that being the way to go. Am I correct in this? Is it possible, with a Namespace Extension to create a new "Folder" object that, upon navigating in to, I can make calls to an API of mine that will determine the subfolders to display?

Comment: Dropbox or Skydrive have local folders (somewhere in C:\Users\$USERNAME) on your hard drive and synchronize these folders with the cloud. For adding a local drive to the "Favorites" like in your screenshot, see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10357/add-your-own-folders-to-favorites-in-windows-7/

Comment: Right. I'm more interested in the synchronization side of things. I'd rather not have a Windows Service running and monitoring the folders, as I doubt that is how Skydrive and Dropbox work.